# Warbler not packaging file using warble war

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy the simple Ruby tutorial app onto a Tomcat server just to get an idea of the workflow. It's my understanding that warbler should package this up to a proper .war file by just running `warble war`.

It runs & deploys to tomcat fine. However, when I try to access the application, I get the error located [here](http://pastebin.com/fG976x1Y).

Specifically, `no such file to load -- thread_safe/jruby_cache_backend`.

After inspecting the specificed thread_safe directory of the packed up war, this is what I find:

```
tomcat@su-server:> ls -l
total 72
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 34843 2014-08-22 16:18 atomic_reference_cache_backend.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  4617 2014-08-22 16:50 cache.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  2040 2014-08-22 16:18 mri_cache_backend.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  2714 2014-08-22 16:18 non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  1346 2014-08-22 16:18 synchronized_cache_backend.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat  1642 2014-08-22 16:18 synchronized_delegator.rb
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 2014-08-22 16:19 util
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   700 2014-08-22 16:18 util.rb
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat   492 2014-08-22 16:18 version.rb
```

jruby_cache_backend is nowhere to be found, and I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Did you add in your warble.rb file these gems?
something like that:
```config.gems << "webrick-1.3.1"```

Comment: No. Do you mean I should add all of the gems to the warbler config so it would package them all up?

Comment: Yep, that's what I suggest you to do :)

Comment: After further reading, it seems like a war that was generated with warble should *just work* without including that stuff?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get warbler to work in our environment, we currently do:

Install copies of gems locally in project:

```
bundle install --path=./bundle
```

Lock and cache gems in .vendor/cache (only have to run once)

```
bundle package --all
```

Finally,

```
bundle update
```

It feels bloated, but it is working for me currently.